# Unir resultados de varias procedures em uma unica tabela

Tags: sql-server

Tenho a seguinte procedure onde passo o nome de uma coluna e ele conta os registros dessa coluna.

```
exec psGraficoestatistica 'Email'
```

Ele retorna uma coluna com o nome `EMAIL` e uma única linha com a quantidade de ocorrências.

Preciso mesclar o resultado de varias procedures como esta em uma unica tabela. É possivel?

```
exec psGraficoestatistica 'Email'
exec psGraficoestatistica 'Blogs'
exec psGraficoestatistica 'Google'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poder utilizar o query abaixo para isto.

```
DECLARE @resultado as table(Email int, Blogs int, Google int)
INSERT INTO @resultado 
SELECT 
    exec psGraficoestatistica 'Email' as Email,
    exec psGraficoestatistica 'Blogs' as Blogs,
    exec psGraficoestatistica 'Google' as Google,

SELECT * FROM @resultado
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize tabela temporária ou variável:

```
CREATE TABLE #resultado (item VARCHAR(50), quantidade INT)
-- DECLARE @resultado TABLE (item VARCHAR(50), quantidade INT)
INSERT #resultado
-- INSERT @resultado
exec psGraficoestatistica 'Email'

INSERT #resultado
exec psGraficoestatistica 'Blogs'
```